# How to format a very long set description?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

How can I format the following very long set description? Ideally, it should split into two lines.

The general structure of the set description is:

`\{f(x) :| x \in S |: P(x)\}`

This is a non-standard set notation, which means: the set obtained by running through all the `x`'s in the set `S`, choosing only those `x`'s that satisfy the predicate `P`, and then applying the function `f` to the selected `x`'s and collecting the results into a set.

Additionally, the left part of the set below is of the form `a \mapsto b` (`b` being the cases structure). This is simply syntactic sugar for the ordered pair `(a,b)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$
\left\{\ddot{\mathbf{A}}_{d(\Omega;\dot{E})}(T.d)[i] \mapsto f_{d(\Omega;\dot{E})}^T(l,u)[i]\ :\!|\ i \in [1..T.d.n]\ |\!:\ F_{d(\Omega;\dot{E})}^T[i-1] \leq u \wedge F_{d(\Omega;\dot{E})}^T[i] \geq l\right\}
$$
\end{document}
```

Here the typeset result is seen in context. It extends into the right margin almost all the way to the right edge of the page.

[image: A very long set description]

---

I've tried using `\split` and `\multlined` as per egreg's suggestion in a comment below.

SPLIT

```
\begin{split}
\left\{\ddot{\mathbf{A}}_{d(\Omega;\dot{E})}(T.d)[i] \mapsto f_{d(\Omega;\dot{E})}^T(l,u)[i]\ &:\!|\ i \in [1..T.d.n]\\
&|\!:\ F_{d(\Omega;\dot{E})}^T[i-1] \leq u \wedge F_{d(\Omega;\dot{E})}^T[i] \geq l\right\}
\end{split}
```

It produces the following error message:

```
Extra }, or forgotten \right.
```

MULTLINED

```
\begin{multlined}[t]
\left\{\ddot{\mathbf{A}}_{d(\Omega;\dot{E})}(T.d)[i] \mapsto f_{d(\Omega;\dot{E})}^T(l,u)[i]\ :\!|\ i \in [1..T.d.n]\\
|\!:\ F_{d(\Omega;\dot{E})}^T[i-1] \leq u \wedge F_{d(\Omega;\dot{E})}^T[i] \geq l\right\}
\end{multlined}
```

It produces the following error message:

```
 Missing \right. inserted.
```

Comment: Not an answer, but to begin with, [don’t use `$$..$$` in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/69818).

Comment: You decide what's a good break point, then use `split` or `multlined`. Where to break is *your* decision.  Anyway, inputting `:|` and `|:` yields a different result than your picture. And `\doto` is undefined.

Comment: @egreg: Sorry. I should have verified that the code works as advertised on a clean document. I've corrected the code now. As for your suggestions: how can I make sure the size of the left and right braces match after I split the line?

Comment: @egreg: The good break points are just before the :| or just before the |:

Comment: And of course you cannot break a left... right pair. You'll need manual scaling for that to work.